# Python Code Runtime Error: In transaction mode using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor, runtimeerror

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "Project Path"

feature1 = arcpy.env.workspace+'TableWithEstimates'
feature2 = arcpy.env.workspace+'TableToJoin'

interval = 7

arcpy.CreateTable_management(arcpy.env.workspace,'JustEstimates')
arcpy.management.AddField('JustEstimates', 'FID', 'TEXT')
arcpy.management.AddField('JustEstimates', 'PRICEEST', 'FLOAT')

cur = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature1, ['IN_FID','ESTPRICE'])
cur2 = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('JustEstimates', ['FID','PRICEEST'])

for row in cur:
    if row[0] % interval == 0:
        cur2.insertRow(row)
    else:
        pass
        
del cur, cur2, row
```

This is an excerpt of the code I am running. The purpose of this is stretch is to take a previously created table and take every seventh row out of it to get the estimates I am looking for. I am going to join this with some other data generated, but need this to work first to match estimate data to another data source.

In Arc's Jupyter platform, I keep getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [2]:
Line 19:    cur2.insertRow(row)

RuntimeError: workspace already in transaction mode
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This makes no sense as other soultions dealing with problem point to it as a versioning issue. I imported all of this data into a default template from emailed files that also required some jigging. The data should not be versioned since I was the one who created it in ArcGIS Pro.

What could be causing this?

At some point, I did enter this line in a previous Jupyter block.

```
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(arcpy.env.workspace)
edit.startEditing(False, False)
```

This addressed the failure of ArcGIS Pro to make the table using the arcpy.CreateTable_management() function. I patched one hole and now I have another and this one is not unpatching.

Comment: Take @BERA point using search cursor and us the keyword 'with' approach like some of the examples at the bottom of the docs page https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm

Comment: As I walked away from the computer I thought that this was the case. I thought this might be it. Thank you @BERA. I do think this might work. Thank you! I am going to use the with for the search cursor anyway just in case.

Comment: @BERA your solution worked. Please feel free to post it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the updatecursor is blocking the insertcursor from inserting new rows? You dont seem to use it for updating records so you might aswell replace da.UpdateCursor with da.SearchCursor:

```
...

cur2 = arcpy.da.InsertCursor('JustEstimates', ['FID','PRICEEST'])

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature1, ['IN_FID','ESTPRICE']) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        if row[0] % interval == 0:
            cur2.insertRow(row)
        
del cur2
```